# Retrieving size of Windows 10 shadowing border

Tags: windows-10

We have an application that draws a colored border around specific application windows and dialogs.

We use [GetWindowRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the rectangle of an application window. But on Windows 10 this function includes the shadowing border resulting in a large gap between our colored border and the application window. So we need to compensate for the shadowing border.

Which API can we use to determine the width of the shadowing border around application windows and dialogs in Windows 10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution. Use [DwmGetWindowAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969515(v=vs.85).aspx) with [DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969530(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the correct size:

```
DwmGetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, &rect, sizeof(rect));
```